# How to connect to MySQL from VB.Net in console mode

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to connect to MySQL from VB.Net in console mode. I have installed Connector/NET from MySQL.

When I try to create a MySqlConnection object the VBC compiler reports that MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection is not defined.

All the advice I can find appears to be directed to configuring Projects in Visual Studio but I don't want to use Visual Studio.

For example, there is advice to reference the connector DLL in the Visual Studio Project specification but I don't know how to implement this advice using VB in console mode without Visual Studio. Similarly, there is advice to copy the MySql.Data.dll to the bin directory of the application. I have tried copying MySql.Data.dll from the Connector/NET assemblies directory to the MySQL server bin directory, but this doesn't help.

I would appreciate any advice.

I'm disappointed that the only response to this posting is a down vote. When I look in the "Related" panel I see terse questions like "How do I connect to MySQL from Python" receiving hundreds of up votes. I'd appreciate advice on how to improve my question. I really need to crack this problem and assume that many readers must have got this working.

I have confirmed that MySQL.Data.dll is apparently correctly installed in directory:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.9

I assume that this is what VBC needs to instantiate a MySqlConnection object.

Comment: Why don't you want to use visual studio? The reason it exists is it makes things like this more painless. If you insist on doing it manually you reference it in the same way as any other reference, linking to the dll I am guessing? I think it is /r or /reference while compiling, it is for C# anyway... You should be able to look this up on MSDN quite easily, did you even try google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a quick google reveals you probably want to use the /r or /reference switch when compiling - passing the path to the DLL with the connector in it...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czhbsf4x.aspx

Although I'll reiterate what I said in my comment, why don't you just use Visual Studio?

Comment: The class I'm working with is restricted to using VB in console mode only.

Comment: @user3069570 The class your working with doesn't work in visual studio? But does with the command line compiler???? I think not... I am now curious - please explain why you think this? Does VS give you an error? What does it say?

Comment: Yes, the class uses the command line compiler vbc. Following your suggestion I call "vbc /reference:MySQL.Data.dll myfile.vb" and it connects to MySQL as required. (To avoid possible confusion "class" here means a class of students.)

Comment: Okay but I am saying - you can indeed use visual studio as it uses THE EXACT SAME COMPILER. So WHY do you think you can't use visual studio? I'm just curious...

Comment: I have never thought that one can't use Visual Studio to do this. I thought that I had made it clear that I wanted to know how to do this in console mode because that's the environment that I'm working in.

Comment: What do you mean console mode? As in you do not have a GUI on your computer? I just am curious why anyone would do that...

Comment: @user3069570 - You said 'I don't want to use Visual Studio', I just can't think of a single reason why that would be the case, and I would like you to explain so I can think of one next time :)

Comment: Use of console mode only is a requirement of the syllabus (Cambridge A Level Computer Science).